# How to generate a random UIColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uicolor

I'm trying to generate a random colour from 8 options. All of the stack overflow posts / tutorials I've found have been ANY random colour. In my prefix.pch I defined 8 different sets of colour definitions this is a single example:

```
#define cola1       209/255.
#define colb1       0/255.
#define colc1       0/255.
#define cold1       1.0/255.
```

**Defining different colour values for cola1-8, colb1-8, colc1-8, and cold1-8.**

Then I set up a random number generator:

```
int randomNumber; 

randomNumber = arc4random() %8;
randomNumber = randomNumber + 1;
whatRandomNumberIs = randomNumber;
```

I then tried setting up an `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cola%i", randomNumber];` inside the `[UIColor colorWithRed etc]`

like this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cola%i", whatRandomNumberIs] green:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"colb%i", whatRandomNumberIs] blue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"colc%i", whatRandomNumberIs] alpha:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cold%i", whatRandomNumberIs]];
```

But then realised you cannot put an `NSString` in a `CGFloat`.

**So now I'm stuck. How would I go about installing a random number from 1-8 inside the red, green, blue and alpha values without doing an NSString stringWithFormat? Is there another way to return a random UIColor value that is defined because I only want it to be specific colours??**

Comment: check [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/monactivityindicatorview),  here he is generating random color... might help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what you can do...

In `prefix.pch` you have as below.

```
#define colorCombination1 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination2 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination3 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination4 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination5 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination6 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination7 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
#define colorCombination8 [UIColor colorWithRed:.... alpha:1.0];
```

Now you create array of this colors..

```
NSArray *myColorArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:colorCombination1, colorCombination2, colorCombination3, colorCombination4, colorCombination5, colorCombination6, colorCombination7, colorCombination8, nil];
```

Now you get random number say variable as `generatedRandomNumber`.

```
UIColor *myRandomColor = [myColorArray objectAtIndex:generatedRandomNumber%8];
```

`generatedRandomNumber%8` will give you remainder from the `generatedRandomNumber`.

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Way you can get random color is by using `hue` , `saturation` and `brightness`

```
//random color
CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 ); // 0.0 to 1.0
CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5; // 0.5 to 1.0, away from white
CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5; // 0.5 to 1.0, away from black
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
```

Comment: I saw that tutorial but I don't see how I can make it between 8 values, because this is for any random color

Comment: @LiamStockhomme : you have defined 8 colors? then put in array and use randomNumber%8 as array index...

Comment: @FahimParkar it didn't work because it didn't let me make it a UIColor

Comment: @LiamStockhomme your are right you will first need to make UIColor instance to use it.

Comment: @LiamStockhomme : you meant array is not allowing to use UIColor in array?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to construct a string at runtime and then use it as the name of a macro that was defined at compile-time.  That doesn't work.  No information about the name of a compile-time macro is available at runtime.

Here is one correct way to choose a random color from a set defined at compile time.  Define a method to return a random color, in a category on `UIColor`:

```
@interface UIColor (Liam_RandomColor)

+ (UIColor *)Liam_randomColor;

@end
```

Implement the method to first (one time only) initialize an array of the predefined colors, and second (every time) to return an element of the array at random:

```
@implementation UIColor (Liam_RandomColor)

+ (UIColor *)Liam_randomColor {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSArray *colors;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        colors = @[
            [UIColor colorWithRed:209/255.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1/255.0],
            [UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.0 green:100/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1],
            // etc.
        ];
    });

    return colors[arc4random_uniform(colors.count)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry if I sound ignorant but what is the best way to insert it into the UIColor and call it?

Comment: Read [“Categories Add Methods to Existing Classes” in *Programming with Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a category on UIColor and wrap your predefined colors in a method, something similar to this:

```
@interface UIColor (myCategory)
+ (UIColor *)randomColorForInt(int n);
@end

@implementation
+ (UIColor *)randomColorForInt(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:cola1 green:colb1 blue:colc1 alpha:cold1]];
    }
    ...
}
@end
```